# How to lock a sheet on Excel using Openyxl and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I am trying to protect an excel sheet with Openyxl in Python, I have tried in different ways but without success. The idea is to create a data entry so that the user can enter data and then verify it in excel without the possibility of modifying it. Only supervisors can modify the information, so they must have the password.

```
import os
import openpyxl
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

def enter_data():
    nombre = first_name_entry.get()
    apellido = last_name_entry.get()
 

    print("Nombre: ", nombre, "Apellido: ", apellido)
    
    filepath= "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Python/Prueba con excel/Viaticos.xlsx"
    if not os.path.exists(filepath):
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        sheet = workbook.active
        heading = ["Nombre", "Apellido"]
        sheet.append(heading)
        workbook.save(filepath)


    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    sheet = workbook.active
    sheet.append([nombre, apellido])
    workbook.save(filepath)

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('Viaticos Neutics')
frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

user_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Informacion Personal")
user_info_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    #Name and last name
first_name_label = tkinter.Label(user_info_frame, text="Nombre")
first_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
last_name_label = tkinter.Label(user_info_frame, text = "Apellido")
last_name_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

    #Name and lastname
first_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(user_info_frame)
first_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
last_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(user_info_frame)
last_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)


window.mainloop()
```

I would like to make something like this:

```
import os
import openpyxl
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

def enter_data():
    nombre = first_name_entry.get()
    apellido = last_name_entry.get()
 

    print("Nombre: ", nombre, "Apellido: ", apellido)
    
    filepath= "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Python/Prueba con excel/Viaticos.xlsx" 
#set a password
    password = "123"
#unprotect the sheet     
    sheet.unprotect.password

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
    sheet = workbook.active

#protect the sheet before save   
    sheet.protect.password
    
    sheet.append([nombre, apellido])
    workbook.save(filepath)

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('Viaticos Neutics')
frame = tkinter.Frame(window)
frame.pack()

user_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Informacion Personal")
user_info_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    #Name and last name
first_name_label = tkinter.Label(user_info_frame, text="Nombre")
first_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
last_name_label = tkinter.Label(user_info_frame, text = "Apellido")
last_name_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

    #Name and lastname
first_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(user_info_frame)
first_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
last_name_entry = tkinter.Entry(user_info_frame)
last_name_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You've posted far too much code. Can you please create a [mcve] that has just enough code to illustrate your problem?

Comment: Your updated code won't run. You have unbalanced quotes and parenthesis. Make sure the code is runnable.

Comment: @BryanOakley its working for me, when executed it will open a window with options to enter the data, when inserting the data it should be entered in excel. For this particular example, I did not add the button that performs the action since it seemed unnecessary to me and I wanted to reduce the code to the simplest

Comment: It can't run. Look at this line: `    filepath= "C:/Users/franc/Documents/Python/Prueba con `. There is no closing quote. Also, please make sure we can actually reproduce the problem. If there is no button, how can we trigger the function?

Comment: @BryanOakley Thats true, I do not understand why the complete code was not copied. Please bear with me, this is my first time using python

Comment: I ready edit the code and try for my self copy and paste, and its working for me. I hope thats helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the help document of Openpyxl. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html At first I didn't understand it but then I understood how it works First you have to import the configuration `"from openpyxl.workbook.protection import WorkbookProtection"` then create a password for the file

```
ws = workbook.active
ws.protection.password = '123'
```

and it would be ready. The file is checked out only when the dataenter performs a modification